# Getting the properties of a JSON object by name

Tags: javascript, json

I'm attempting to use JSON to hold information about a set of videos. I have successfully read the JSON file, but when attempting to access the properties of that object I'm having some difficulty. When I try to access the array "fastvideos", although the array is loaded as the object, `obj.fastvideos[x]` remains undefined.

Is this a problem with my JSON, or with how I'm trying to access the object?

**JSON**

```
{
"fastvideos": [{
    "video-title": "sampletitle",
    "video-tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3",
    "video-desc": "sample-desc",
    "video-url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<redacted>"
    }, {
    "video-title": "sampletitle2",
    "video-tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3",
    "video-desc": "sample-desc-2",
    "video-url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<redacted>"
    }]
}
```

**JS**

```
var obj = $.getJSON("videolist.json", function(json){
console.log(json);
});

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
obj.fastvideos[1].video-title + ": URL =  " + obj.fastvideos[1].video-url;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hyphen character requires you to use bracket-notation to access the properties `video-title` and `video-url`.

Also, the call to `getJSON` does not return the JavaScript object, but instead returns a reference to a `jqXHR` object.  You don't really need to use that object in your case since you have a function that is listening for a successful callback.  The parameter of that function will contain the parsed JavaScript object.

```
$.getJSON("videolist.json", function(obj){
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
    obj.fastvideos[1]["video-title"] + ": URL =  " + obj.fastvideos[1]["video-url"];
});
```

How to iterate the videos:

```js
var obj = 
{
"fastvideos": [{
    "video-title": "sampletitle",
    "video-tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3",
    "video-desc": "sample-desc",
    "video-url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<redacted>"
    }, {
    "video-title": "sampletitle2",
    "video-tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3",
    "video-desc": "sample-desc-2",
    "video-url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<redacted>"
    }]
};

for (var i = 0; i < obj.fastvideos.length; i++) {
    var video = obj.fastvideos[i];
    var title = video["video-title"];
    var tags =  video["video-tags"];
    var desc =  video["video-desc"];
    var url =  video["video-url"];
    
    console.log(i + " : " + title + " : " + tags + " : " + desc + " : " + url);
}
```

Comment: Someone else posted something about iteration, if you saw it could you possibly expand on it?

Comment: I'm still having an issue with `obj` not containing `fastvideos` - specifically, "TypeError: obj.fastvideos is undefined". This is at the start of the for loop.

Comment: However, I've just noticed that it does seem to exist somewhere: http://i.imgur.com/oLg3zYP.png

Comment: I see the issue now... `$.getJSON` returns a `jqXHR` object which is not what you are looking for.  You are already listing for a callback, so I've rearranged the code a bit.  Please try my updated solution.  Thanks!

Comment: OK, there's some better results. Am I correct in thinking everything has to be done inside the `getJSON()` method? Currently, everything inside it is working, but the iteration (outside of the method) is not, even with `var obj` declared seperately

Comment: I think what you are saying makes sense.  Another way to think about this is that you won't have the data until the callback function is invoked.  If you move the processing code inside your function you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var tArray = {
"fastvideos":
    [   {
            "video-title": "sampletitle",
            "video-tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3",
            "video-desc": "sample-desc",
            "video-url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<redacted>"
        }, 
        {
            "video-title": "sampletitle2",
            "video-tags": "tag1, tag2, tag3",
            "video-desc": "sample-desc-2",
            "video-url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<redacted>"
        }
    ]
};


alert(tArray["fastvideos"][0]["video-title"])

for(var i=0; i<tArray["fastvideos"].length; i++){
    alert( tArray["fastvideos"][i]["video-title"] );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gj1u6rpm/1/